# Azure Monitor metrics based on sum of existing metric values

Tags: azure, azure-monitor

I have a network resource that only has bytes in and bytes out as metrics, I want to derive another metric with the addition of both bytesin+bytesout. Please suggest how I can add both in & out values and create an Azure Monitor Alert rule based on this new metric.

Comment: Those are currenly 2 seperate metrics?

Comment: Yes for that resource under MatrciName as column these are two different metrics bytesin and bytesout.we need to calculate sum of these as totalbytes

Comment: Based on what? I suppose they have different timestamps? You could sum all bytesin and bytesout values for a short period and report on that. Would that be a solution?

Comment: Yes these have different timestamps. Can you suggest query so a new column such as Totalbytes comes as sum of bytesin and bytesout for last 24 hours duration

Comment: What network resource are we talking about? We need that to know the exact metrics name and the name of the table to look for.

Comment: Express route circuit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-monitoring-metrics-alerts#expressroute-metrics     BitsInPerSecondTraffic and BitsoutPerSecondTraffic  . I need to derive total of these two

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a new metric by combining to existing ones. However, you can create an Alert Rule on a [custom query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/monitor-expressroute#sample-kusto-queries). That means we can create a query like this

```
AzureMetrics
| where MetricName == "BitsInPerSecondTraffic" or MetricName == "BitsoutPerSecondTraffic"
| where ResourceType == "EXPRESSROUTECIRCUITS"
| summarize AggregatedValue = sum(Total) by bin(TimeGenerated, 15m)
```

Use that query to create an alert using [the azure portal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/alerts-based-on-analytics-query-using-custom-log-search/):

[image]